# XCode 6 editor and the escape key

Tags: xcode6

XCode 6 shows a very annyoing behavior wrt the escape key: pressing that key inserts the ESC char code (0x1B) at the caret position, instead of canceling dialogs and such (which is especially annyoing with autocompletion and also in the search bar). Since this character is an invisible you will get a syntax error for what looks like absolutely perfect code and you don't know why:

[image]

By enabling Editor -> Show Invisibles you then understand why:

[image]

if you come to the idea that there could something be hidden.

Does anybody know how to fix this behavior? Confirmations that other see the same effect? If not it might be something with my installation (plugins?).

Comment: Can you easily try this under a fresh user account?

Comment: Right, doesn't happen with a new account. I also tested without any 3rd party plugin but that did not change the behavior.

Comment: So the problem is solved. Migrate into a new user account.

Comment: @matt: while a solution, it only circumvents the problem. But it may be some unsuspected interaction between installed programs and/or extensions, so impossible to find out where ...

Comment: But no one else in the world but the OP has ever seen this - exactly because it _is_ some unsuspected interaction. The only way to escape (sorry) the interaction is to start over in a clean environment, as you and the OP have already demonstrated. Circumventing the problem is exactly what the OP should want to do at this point! Personally, I would say, run, don't walk, out of this user account. And in future, _keep_ things clean.

Comment: I sympathize with @Jongware. While the new account solves this very specific problem (and opens many new ones, like setting up all the system, access rights etc.) it's not really a solution and doesn't explain why this **only** happens with XCode 6. I have never seen this with other XCode versions, nor does any other text editor, I use, show this behavior. IMO XCode 6 is so buggy that it hurts and I'd rather find out what my problem is and fix only that.

Comment: I can confirm I am also experiencing this behavior, only for one user on my Mac.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this in the future, I had the same problem and found a solution.

In my case, the default key binding for the escape key (Cancel) had been lost, which I guess is what normally keeps the key press from inserting the actual ESC character. Reverting the key binding for Cancel to ESC solved it.

(I found out by looking at key bindings in the preferences panel and showing only those that had been customized. Cancel was in the list even though I can't ever remember having altered it, not sure if that was something I had done or caused by a bug somewhere).

Comment: Thank you! You saved me the day! It's really easy to create such dumb binding by trying to cancel key binding editing with "Esc".

This answer should be marked as solution!

Comment: Bless you and the horse you rode in on... This has been plaguing me for weeks. Today I had finally figured out it was Esc characters in my code and then I found your suggestion above with the fix :).

Comment: By the powers invested in me, I hope you'll meet a big pile of gold by the end of this year. This is the one solution that really solves it